# App submitted to iTunes from the Xcode organiser is not visible under MyApps in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have built an app from Xcode 6 and I can export and validate the app, but when I submit the app it is not visible anywhere in the MyApps section in iTunes Connect.
I have no idea as to where the app has gone.

I can access the app from my iPhone when I select adhoc distribution, but it is nowhere listed in iTunes Connect.

Can someone please help me out?? I've been working on this for more than 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Fist add the app in iTunes Connect, before you export and validate it in Xcode.
In iTunes Connect, go to 'My Apps' and click the plus sign in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your application into **"Prerelease"** in MyApp. And then you can see your application in **Version -> Build** section.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i submitted the app once again from XCode and now it shows under prereleases in MyApps.
Think it was some issue with XCode.

Thanks for the same.